# A note on Doob's theorem

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, probability-distributions, martingales

I have faced the following problem, regarding to the Martingale Theory. Because this area far from my area I don't know whether this problem is in literature or this can be simple question for specialists of this area. If like this things in any literature can someone suggest me?

Let
$$
(\mathbb{P}_{n}(t))_{n \in \mathbb{N}_{0}} =
\left( \left\{
I^{n}_{j}(t),~ 
1\leq j \leq q_{n}(t) \}
\right\} \right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}_{0}}
$$
be a sequence of  partitions of $ [0,1)$ depending on parameter $t\in J\subset (0,1)$ such that 
$$
\underset{t\in J}{\sup}\underset{1\leq j\leq q_{n}(t)}{\max}|I^{n}_{j}(t)|\leq \lambda ^{n} 
$$
for some $\lambda \in (0,1)$ and for any $t\in J$ we have $q_{n}(t)\rightarrow \infty.$

Suppose that $ f $ is $ 1 $-periodic and that $ f \in {L^{p}}([0,1) $, where $ p > 1 $. 
Next, for any $t\in J,$ we define a sequence $ (G_{n}(\cdot, t): [0,1) \to \mathbb{C})_{n \in \mathbb{N}_{0}} $ of functions by
$$
\forall n \in \mathbb{N}_{0}, ~ \forall x \in [0,1), ~
\forall j \in \{ 1,\ldots, q_{n}(t)  \}: \\
{G_{n}}(x, t) \stackrel{\text{df}}{=}
\frac{1}{\left| I^{n}_{j}(t) \right|} \int_{I^{n}_{j}(t)} f(s) ~ \mathrm{d}{s}, \quad
\text{if $ x \in I^{n}_{j}(t) \in D_{n}(t) $}.
$$
Assume that for any $t\in J$ the random value $G_{n}(\cdot, t)$ is a $L^{p}$ bounded martingale w.r.t $\mathbb{P}_{n}(t).$ It is well known (according to Doob's theorem) 
$$
G_{n}(\cdot, t)\rightarrow f, \,\,\,a.s.
$$ 
and 
$$
E(|G_{n}(\cdot, t)-f|^{p})\rightarrow 0.
$$

> **Question.** Is it true
>   $$
> \underset{t\in J}{\sup}E(|G_{n}(\cdot, t)-f|^{p})\rightarrow 0?
> $$

Since the lengths of atoms of partitions uniformly tend to zero, I think it is true, but I do not know how to show it.

Comment: Does $E$ here simply mean integration over $[0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure?  Intuitively, it seems to me that using martingale methods here is overkill; this looks like it may just need some clever calculus.  For instance, if $f$ is continuous you get uniform convergence of $G_n$ to $f$, and the uniform distance between $G_n$ and $f$ depends only on the mesh size and the modulus of continuity of $f$.  I don't see offhand how to do the $L^p$ case, though.

Comment: @NateEldredge. $E$ is usual Lebesgue integral. Yes you are right, if the lengths of atoms of partition are same then it can be shown $$\underset{t\in J}{\sup}E(|G_{n}(\cdot, t)-f|^{p})\leq 2\underset{|h|\leq \lambda^{n}}{\sup}E(|f(x+ h)-f(x)|^{p})$$. But in the case of different lengths I have got some problem

Answer (score 1):

It is true. Here is an elementary proof, without relying on the martingale convergence theorem.

Let us first consider the case when $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous. If $I\subseteq [0,1]$ is an interval of length $|I|$ which contains $x$, define the modulus of continuity of $f$ as
$$m_f(\delta):=\sup\{| f(s) - f(t)|: s,t\in [0,1]: |s-t|<\delta\}, \quad \delta>0,$$
and notice that $m_f:(0,1)\to [0,\infty)$ is increasing and $\lim_{\delta \downarrow 0} m_f(\delta) = 0$, since $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$.
The bound
$$\Big|f(x)-\frac{1}{|I|}\int_{I} f(s)ds \Big|\leq m_f(\delta),$$
clearly holds, and implies that
$$\| f - G_n(t,\cdot)\|_{L^p} \leq \sup_{x\in [0,1]}|f(x) - G_n(t,x)|\leq m_{f}(\lambda^n) \quad \forall t\in J, $$
and so in this case the thesis follows from $\lim_{\delta \downarrow 0} m_f(\delta) = 0$ and $0<\lambda^n \to 0$.

For later use notice that, since $G_n(t,\cdot)$ is the conditional expectation $E[f|\mathcal{F}_n(t)]$ of $f$ with respect to the sigma algebra $\mathcal{F}_n(t)$ generated by the partition $\mathbb{P}_n(t)$ (using the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$ as the underlying probability), we have proved that
$$\sup_t \|f- E[f|\mathcal{F}_n(t)]\|_{L^p}\to 0 \text{ as } n\to \infty, \quad \text{ for any continuous $f$}.$$

To treat the case of a general $f\in L^p$, we approximate it with a continuous $g$. So, choose $\epsilon>0$ and find $g:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ continuous such that $ \| f - g\|_{L^p} \leq \epsilon $. Since  the conditional expectation is a  linear contraction in $L^p$ we have that
$$\|E[f|\mathcal{F}_n(t)]- E[g|\mathcal{F}_n(t)]\|_{L^p}\leq \| f -g \|_{L^p} \quad \text{ for all } t\in J.$$
Thus, adding and subtracting $g- E[g|\mathcal{F}_n(t)]$ from $f- E[f|\mathcal{F}_n(t)]$ and applying the triangle inequality we find that
$$\|f- E[f|\mathcal{F}_n(t)]\|_{L^p}\leq 2\| f -g \|_{L^p}+\|g- E[g|\mathcal{F}_n(t)]\|_{L^p}.$$
Since $g$ is continuous, as we proved above there exist $k$ s.t.
$$\sup_t \|g- E[g|\mathcal{F}_n(t)]\|_{L^p}\leq \epsilon\quad  \text{ for all } n\geq k, $$
and thus $\sup_{t\in J}\|f- E[f|\mathcal{F}_n(t)]\|_{L^p}\leq 3\epsilon $  for all $n\geq k$, proving the thesis.